# .Include() method in APIController with one-to-many relations?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

One display should have many media(images, videos) in my project. I'm using Entity Framework Core to build my database, and CRUD with my API Controller.

I designed my Model classes as such:

```
[Table("Displays")]
public class Display : ConcurrencyCheck
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} skal udfyldes!")]
    [Display(Name = "Display navn")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Display tændt")]
    public bool IsOn { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Display beskrivelse")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Video> Videos { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Media : ConcurrencyCheck
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} skal udfyldes!")]
    [Display(Name = "Medie navn")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Medie beskrivelse")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Medie filtype")]
    public string FileType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} skal udfyldes!")]
    [Display(Name = "Medie filsti")]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public int? DisplayId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DisplayId")]
    public Display Display { get; set; }
}

[Table("Videos")]
public class Video : Media
{
    [Display(Name = "Frames")]
    public int Frames { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Filsti på undetekster")]
    public string SubtitlesPath { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Filsti på thumbnail")]
    public string ThumbnailPath { get; set; }
}

[Table("Images")]
public class Image : Media
{
}

public abstract class ConcurrencyCheck
{
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And my API controllers are scaffolded with 'API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework'.

Currently in the api-controller 'DisplaysController', I don't see the `.Include(x => x.Media)`, though I read somewhere it's used? One display should have many media(images, videos).

Should I include it somehow somewhere, or does it do that automatically by the models I have?

Comment: Of course you should customize generated code according to your specifications. Scaffolding is just a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scaffolded with API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework` just provide the most basic five database operation methods -- `select` , `select by id`, `update`, `add` and `delete`. Its purpose is to help users build basic `crud` faster and more easily. You can add your own code on the default code template.

**The default code template**

[image]

**Add your own code**

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) and their "text" won't appear in search engines.